# file Upload causing issues other than PDF files

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, pdf, file-upload

```
const uploadData = new FormData();
      uploadData.append("engfile",fileObj.originFile);
const [response,error] = yield call(() => fetch(`http://localhost:44361/api/v1/files?fileName=${payload.name}&fileSize=${payload.size}`, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: uploadData,
        headers:{
             'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data;',
             'token':'token'
        }
      })
       .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((result) => {
        console.log('Success:', result);
        // yield put({type:"UPLOAD_SUCCESS",data:response.data})
        return result;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        return error;
      }));
```

I am trying to upload a file from UI to server but the above code works perfect for PDF files but if I send .docx or image files in browser since .docX and .xlsx files are writable, file gets even boundary values along with content-type. how to avoid this using fetch API ?

The above code perfectly for pdf file since it's not writable,but for other files it does not, how to resolve this at UI level or do we have to take care at the API level (nodejs at the API end), could you please guide me here ?

On PDF Browser requeset :
[image]

Comment: ` file gets even boundary values along with content-type` what do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean as you can see in the screenshot content-type/metadata gets written in the payload, how should I avoid it ? or I can't from UI ? I need to something right for other than PDF files

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't override `Content-Type` header as internally browser sets the [boundary](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html)

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryUpNj05W8fQrQrefK
```

**Example: when you run this and see network panel the header mentioned is set**

```js
const formData = new FormData();

const testFile = new Blob([], {
  type: 'text/plain'
})

formData.append("testFile", testFile)

console.log([...formData.entries()])

fetch("/test", {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formData
}).catch(error => {

});
```

Comment: yes you are correct, Why the size 0 ("size": 0,) in the code snippet result ?

Comment: I created empty blob for demonstration purposes.